# Unity desktop entry

Tags: linux-mint, menu, unity

I have installed [Unity](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download). I can use it from directory. But, I want to use it from `menu bar`. Look at my below image

[image]

But the application is right there.

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A desktop entry sample.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Unipro UGENE
Comment=Unipro UGENE is a cross-platform visual environment for DNA and protein sequence analysis.
Exec=/home/samuel/ugene-1.11.5/ugene -ui
Path=/home/samuel/ugene-1.11.5/
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/32/access.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Development;
```

Desktop entries for applications, or .desktop files, are generally a combination of meta information resources and a shortcut of an application. These files usually reside in /usr/share/applications/ or /usr/local/share/applications/ for applications installed system-wide, or ~/.local/share/applications/ for user-specific applications. User entries take precedence over system entries.

[Wiki.ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries)